# Wait Until Website Internal Search Has Completed Using VBA

Tags: vba

I am really struggling to get my VBA code to wait until a website I am accessing, finishes an internal search it is performing.

So far I have tried:

```
Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop     

Set doc = ie.document     

Do While doc.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
```

but it does not work. I could post the html 'refresh' function if that would help?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
It is using the following function which I have gathered from the source code:

```
var limit="5"; 
function beginrefresh()
{ 
if (!document.images) return;
if (limit==1) 
    document.getElementsByTagName("Form")[0].submit(); 
else
   { 
      limit-=1; 
      window.status="Page will refresh in " + limit + " seconds."; 
      setTimeout("beginrefresh()",1000);
   } 
} 

window.onload = function () { beginrefresh(); }
```

**EDIT**

I have cracked it and it was really simple in the end. I used the following to search for a known id on the page that was being loaded. So when it found this id it knew that the code could continue. A very useful technique IF you know an the name of an id on the page loading.

```
Do


Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Set doc = ie.document

Do While doc.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop


Set testobject = ie.document.getElementById("changeFilterCriteria")

   If Not testobject Is Nothing Then Exit Do
```

Loop

**EDIT**

Or maybe not - it does work for about 5 or 6 times in a row but then crashes on

```
Set testobject = ie.document.getElementById("changeFilterCriteria")
```

IE comes up with 'internet explorer cannot display the webpage',

If I then click back and then refresh the page is still performing its internal search.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Jim

Comment: What's an "internal" search?  More code would be useful I think...

Comment: It is using the following function which I have gathered from the source code: var limit="5"

function beginrefresh(){
 if (!document.images)
  return
 if (limit==1)
  document.getElementsByTagName( 'Form' )[0].submit()
 else{ 
  limit-=1
  window.status="Page will refresh in " + limit + " seconds."
  setTimeout("beginrefresh()",1000)
 }
}


window.onload = function ()
{

beginrefresh()

Comment: How do I add a full comment and also use proper code tags?

Comment: @Jim77 you can't. You should update your original question to include the code snippet(s) instead of putting them in comments.

Comment: Try something like: `While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend`

Comment: @ David Zemens thanks for the code but does not wait until the internal search refresh is completed

Comment: What does this page actually do? It seems like it just refreshes itself at 5,4,3 and 2 second intervals and then submits a form.  Where does that form point to ? Another page?

Comment: From the users point of view it displays "Please wait while your document is being processed" and a yellow circle with increasing white segments taken out of it. I think this occurs for 5 seconds and then it checks (I assume) if all the data has been gathered and then shows the data else repeats the process. Does that help at all? What other code could I add to help?

Comment: The page is setup so that the left hand margin stays the same but the refresh part take place on the centre and right parts...

Comment: Are there any professional sites where you cqn pay to guarantee a solution?

Comment: A bit difficult to provide an answer without the full source of the page or a URL to look at.

Comment: Do you want the full source code for the page?

Comment: Yes, the full source would be useful (feel free to snip out parts you know aren't relevant).  A URL would be better though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky situation that I have come across numerous times as well. The traditional "Do...Until" loop with IE.ReadyState doesn't work *after* the first time the page is accessed, mostly because IE and Excel are out of synch at that point.  The best approach I've found is to use a Boolean flag in a "Do...If" loop, where the flag is triggered by a reference to an element in the page you're refreshing.  Until the page refreshes, the flag will be in one state. As long as the flag is in that state, the Do loop continues.  So, somewhere after you've instructed the page to refresh, insert the following code (be sure to adapt for your specific circumstance):

```
Dim flag as Boolean: flag = False
Dim lng_cnt as long: long_cnt = 0
Dim elem_temp as IHTMLElement: Set elem_temp = IE.document.getElementById("*element_name*")
Do Unitl flag = True or lng_cnt = 30
    If elem_temp Is Nothing Then
        flag = False
    Else
        flag = True
        Exit Do
    End If
    lng_cnt = lng_cnt +1
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Loop
```

Note: I added the counter (lng_cnt) to prevent infinite looping. It instructs the program to wait 1 second before continuing if the page hasn't loaded yet, and will discontinue after 30 seconds; because you never know if the page's server is down or whatever. Hope this helps.